# Multithreaded Mail server

Tags: server, postfix

I need to create a multuthreaded mail server on ubuntu 14.04. So i opted for Postfix which is default smtp server on ubuntu. but now I am stuck with multithreading in postfix. how can i perform multithreading in postfix? i came to know about multiple instance management in postfix (http://www.postfix.org/postmulti.1.html) but I am confused on how to perform multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-instance is not equal changing the number of threads. The term multi-instance is used to have multiple distinct instances running.

If you wanna change the number of threads allowed to spawn for different subsystems of postfix, maybe have a look at the performance tuning? 
http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#proc_limit